# KL divergence between hidden layer and arbitrary distribution (Keras/TensorFlow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

I'm implementing an autoencoder in Keras, let's say something like:

```
...
x = Input(shape=(original_dim,))
h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(x)
z = Dense(latent_dim)(h)
output = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='sigmoid')(z)
...
```

My goal is to make `z` behave like an arbitrary distribution, like a Gaussian with zero mean and unit variance. 
This is a slightly different setting than the classical VAE, because here my latent space is not generating the mean and variance of the distribution, but rather it should generate the distribution itself.

A logical solution would be to minimize the KL divergence between `z` and the custom distribution, but I have no idea how to do this. 
In pseudo-code, I would need to do something like:

```
def custom_loss(z):
    my_distribution = ???
    return kl_divergence(z, my_distribution)
```

Is this even doable? Would it be possible to use `tf.contrib.distributions` to achieve this, somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want something like an Empirically defined distribution like Edward has: http://edwardlib.org/api/ed/models/Empirical?

Do you mind filing a request at https://github.com/tensorflow/probability?

I think you would be able to do then 
kl_divergence(Empirical(z), my_distribution), which would compute the summation for you.

Comment: I completely forgot about the question. It turned out that I needed adversarial autoencoders to do the trick. Yes, anyway I would have needed something like Empirical.